# Why Can't I Reference a TextBox by ID When it's in a CreateUserWizard Control?

Tags: asp.net, element, code-behind

I got a wierd problem here.

Inside an asp.net CreateUserWizard, I got some elements, but I can't seem to access them from my code-behind.

Here's a code snippet:

**Markup:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateUserWizard.ascx.cs" Inherits="Web.UserControls.CreateUserWizard" %>
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatingUser="CreatingUser">
<WizardSteps>
    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table border="0">
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="requiredField"/>
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NameRequiredFieldValidator">Navn:</asp:Label>                      
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ShareInfoCheckBox" runat="server" Checked="True" Text="Share my information with partner sites." />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="Name" ErrorMessage="Du skal indtaste dit navn" 
                            ToolTip="Du skal indtaste dit navn" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
</WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

.. And here's the codebehind:

```
public partial class CreateUserWizard : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void CreatingUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Name. //no intellisense and compiler error when I try to access Name
    }
}
```

Shouldn't this work? It's inside a UserControl if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
TextBox nameTextBox =
  CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Name") as TextBox;

if (nameTextBox != null) {
    /* Do your stuff */
}
```

More examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.aspx).

Comment: I prefer the "as TextBox" notation it's less likely to throw an exception

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.FindControl("Name")).Text = "Hello";
```

The reason for this is that your textbox is inside another object, so you cant access it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something else called 'Name' somewhere, a member variable, or a property?  Try giving the control a less generic name like "Navn" or something less likely to conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Sean Bright has the right idea for how to get to it.

As far as "Why": this is a templated control, so the item you are trying to access exist inside of another naming container. You can use the Control.FindControl function to get access to the controls you need.

[This is a good article that explains templated controls.](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/02/25/Understanding-the-naming-container-hierarchy-of-ASP.NET-databound-controls.aspx)

Or in the case of the other predefined fields for this wizard control, you can use CreateUserWizard1.UserName/Email/Password etc to access those values.